# How to dynamically load and initialize a module with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here is the setup of a website I'm working on:

I have multiple types of pages. Each page have a (known) number of js views(components), encapsulated in modules. For each page type I create its own entry point. Previously I used RequireJS and rjs for bundling, so I had a special module (called 'loader'), which could load and initialize each view.

So basically, I have such a structure

```
-news.js
-homepage.js
-components
    |
    -header.js
    -menu.js
    -search.js
    -article.js
    -loader.js
```

and my news.js is

```
require('components/header');
require('components/search');
require('components/article');

var loader = require('components/loader');

loader.initAll();
```

and my homepage.js is

```
require('components/header');
require('components/search');
require('components/menu');

var loader = require('components/loader');

loader.initAll();
```

Each component looks like

```
<div class="js-component" data-component="components/article"></div>
```

And inside loader.js I would like to see something like

```
module.exports = {
    initAll: function () {
        // get all components on the page
        var components = document.querySelectorAll('.js-component');

        components.forEach(function(component) {
            component.name = component.getAttribute('data-component');

            // next is obviously not working with webpack, but is what I need
            require(component.name).init();
        })
    }
}
```

How should I organize this with webpack?

Comment: Maybe the webpack [AMD](https://webpack.github.io/docs/amd.html) could help?